# How can I keep Wordpress from stripping out my <p> and <br> tags?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress strips out `<p>` and `<br>` tags when switching between the visual and the text editors. Well, to be specific, it doesn't actually strip them out of the content, but it does not display them in the text editor view. Is there a way to stop it from hiding those tags?

I know about the [tinymce advanced plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/), but is there a way to stop this behavior on a per-post/per-page basis without having to install the plugin?

Answer (score 6):

If you add a meaningless data attribute to the `<p>` and `<br>` tags, they will continue to show.

### Example

When switching from text to visual editor and back, the following text

```
<p>Some paragraph text <br> and a second line.</p>
```

becomes

```
Some paragraph text
and a second line.
```

However,

```
<p data-x>Some paragraph text <br data-x> and a second line.</p>
```

makes the tags remain visible:

```
<p data-x="">Some paragraph text <br data-x="" /> and a second line.</p>
```

This is useful on pages with more complex layouts that can shift around when the tags get stripped.

Comment: Did you ask yourself a question, and then answer it 30 seconds later? Or am I just missing something...

Comment: @rnevius, yes. It's called "share your knowledge Q&A Style" See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Hey, cool. I knew answering your own questions was OK, but was unaware of the "share your knowledge" style. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I'm glad you both shared your knowledge here.

Answer (score 0):

If the post is custom post type, you can add meta box with [add_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) and there you can initialize your own editor with [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) which can be customized. For example you can pass settings to the **tinymce** like `force_p_newslines` which should force every new line to start with new paragraph